# How to disable lxc container login prompt on centos 7

Tags: centos, lxc

I have created an LXC container on CentOS 7. Every time I do `sudo lxc-start -n mycontainer` I'm greeted with a login prompt:

```
...
[  OK  ] Started Console Getty.
[  OK  ] Started Command Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Reached target Login Prompts.
[  OK  ] Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
[  OK  ] Started Login Service.

mycontainer login: root
Password: 
Login incorrect
```

Doint CTRL+C or CTRL+Z won't get rid of it, which means I can't use this terminal anymore. However, on another terminal I can SSH into the container using the exact same password that is rejected above. I also tried `root:root` as I read somewhere that it would be the default.

All I want to do now is disable this login prompt so I can just use either `lxc-attach` or SSH to get a console. In Ubuuntu I never get a login prompt as default, is there a way to disable it on CentOS LXC to get the same behaviour? I looked up `man lxc.container.conf` but couldn't find anything useful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable the login prompt on request, it should be started as a daemon, as follows:

```
sudo lxc-start -n mycontainer -d
```

The manual says this is the default behaviour (which I see in my Ubuntu machine) but for some reason it is not on this CentOS container on a CentOS host, and I'd still like to see answers showing how to restore the default behavior (start as a daemon).

Comment: Just comparing two debian versions ([jessie](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/lxc/lxc-start.1)'s and [stretch](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/lxc/lxc-start.1)'s) I can see the default behaviour changed: that was `-F` before, and it's `-d` after. So I think there's no behaviour to restore. I guess CentOS 8 will be using `-d` as default when released.